# Sum divide by zero columns

Tags: reporting-services

First time posting, long time reading. I'm stumped.

Using report builder.

I'm trying to create a report, that is from inherited code, the query that pulls the data potentially allows a 0 in a numerator and divisor, so I've had to produce around that to display the figures in the report and not get the #Error. However, when I try and create a summary of the summed output, because I think the underlying maths still gives a 0, it won't sum.

[image: Table1]

The rows will change based on date parameters, and I have conditional formatting of the recovery column based on parameters, ie. recovery below 90 or above 110.

This works so far for single and multi days, however I'd like to include a summary box whereby I get a "Total runs", "runs outside parameters" and then a % based on those figures. I get the total runs with `=countdistinct(Fields!runnumber.Value, "dsMain")` but I can't for the life of my get a number of runs outside tolerance.

Help greatly appreciated on this one.
Thanks

After multiple attempts my current textbox for what should hopefully give a figure for total out of tolerance is

`=Sum( IIf(Code.Divider(Sum(Fields!OUTPUTwt.Value),  Sum(Fields!INPUTwt.Value))*100<=Parameters!LowerYield.Value or Code.Divider(Sum(Fields!OUTPUTwt.Value),  Sum(Fields!INPUTwt.Value))*100 > Parameters!UpperYield.Value , 1 , 0) )`

But it only ever gives 1, so it's stopping after the first. Or just something else is broken elsewhere.

Comment: I would check the `Divider` function parameter types. The numbers may be set to integer.

Comment: The divider was what I scooped from here
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double) 
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0 
Return 0 
Else 
Return Dividend/Divisor 
End If 
End Function

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things..

First, make sure that your `divider` function is returning the values you expect.

Once you are happy with that then your code is wrong if I understood what you are trying to do.

I'm assuming you have a bunch of rows in your dataset that you are grouping within your report (by product number?). You then want to look at each group and check if it's outside tolerance, you then want to count how many instances are out of tolerance.

As it stands, you code has no scope, so it will include all the data within the scope of the textbox, if the textbox is in the outer group (like in a grand total) then each `SUM()` will sum all the data for the entire range. Basically it's only doing one calculation across (probably) all your data.

I've not no data to test with but try changing all your inner `SUM()`s to include the group scope, so use the rowgroup name of the rowgroup you want to individually evaluate. Assuming your RowGroup is called, say, `ProdNum` then change all the **inner** `SUM()`s from

```
Sum(Fields!OUTPUTwt.Value)
```

to

```
Sum(Fields!OUTPUTwt.Value, "ProdNum")
```

Don't change the outer sum though (the one at the start of your expression).